# Removing null columns with U-SQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have many files that I'm attempting to join together. I happen to know that many of the columns in each of these files contain nothing but null values and I can do without having them in there. How can I write a U-SQL statement to extract the data from the files, check for columns of nothing but nulls and exclude them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most performing approach would probably be to write a custom extractor that just skips the rows that are just containing null values.

Otherwise, you could write something like this (note the null indicators on the non-object types):

```
@data = EXTRACT c1 string, c2 int?, c3 DateTime? // ... more columns
        FROM "/path/file.csv"
        USING Extractors.Csv();

@data = SELECT * FROM @data WHERE c1 != null AND c2 != null AND c3 != null;
```

(note that you will have to most likely cast the `null` to the column type in the comparison).

If your schema is different between the different files, you could also do the filter using a so-called processor that can look at the schema of the input row.
Something along the line of

```
@data = PROCESS @data PRODUCE c1 string, c2 int?, c3 DateTime? 
        USING new MyAsm.NullFilterProcessor();
```

Where you would have to implement the `NullFilterProcessor` as an `IProcessor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@data = EXTRACT c1 string, c2 int?, c3 DateTime? // ... more columns
    FROM "/path/file.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();
```

Sometimes the above code will also show error, whenever the null values are already replaced with some other values like "", "\N", null, etc.

> USING Extractors.Csv(nullEscape:"\N");

so we have to use nullEscape parameter in the default Extractor in order to exclude the null values in the file.